# @Firebase The event listener for retrieve data does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, addeventlistener

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
/******************************After declaration**************************************/

    userIDDatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("login");
    userIDDatabaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.w("Show out:", "In Firebase ValueEventListener");
       LoginClass tempClass=dataSnapshot.getValue(LoginClass.class);
            loginID=tempClass.getLoginID();
                 }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Database Error: "+databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

[image]
above is my coding, I wanna retrieve `loginID` but my event listener does not fire as the log.w did't not print any log in my logcat, I think my function does not trigger the `onDataChange()` because every time it will return null for the `loginID`. Can someone tell me what am I missing?? I referred to all documentation related, I really don't figure out what is the problem over here.

thank you~~

Comment: why your userIDDatabaseReference pointed at "login" ?

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui, ops, my fault, I was suppose retrieve the loginID from login node, please refer to the picture below there

Comment: Check if the uid is the same or not and also check if onDataChange function called or not ?

Comment: onDataChange function is not been call as the log does not print out? am I missing something in my coding? the UID is correct btw

Answer (score 0):

Use a single value event listener to get the data one time. Use this code:

```
userIDDatabaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.w("Show out:", "In Firebase ValueEventListener");
   LoginClass tempClass=dataSnapshot.getValue(LoginClass.class);
        loginID=tempClass.getLoginID();
             }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("Database Error: "+databaseError.getDetails());
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, I will try on this, but my problem is related with the event listener ??